# Gif hides before fully played

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gif, fadeout

I have a full-screen .gif animation that starts when the user accesses the home page and then fadeOut reviewing the page's content. The thing is, depending on the computer and its internet, there is a delay and sometimes the animation end up hiding before it has been fully viewed.

I am using the code below to hide the div that allocates the animation based on the duration it has (around 10s). I don't know if it is possible, but I would like to hide it after it as been fully played/load(not sure) and not after a specific amount of time.

```
$(".animation").delay(9500).fadeOut(400);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the code in a separate JS file (or update the current file and test it) and then...rather than using the $(document).ready, use the $(window).load

The window load event will execute after the page is fully loaded, including all the frames, objects, images, etc.

Comment: Hello, Brian! Thank you for your tip. I noticed a slight difference, but I guess the method I am using to fade out the animation is not the best for the situation. I still have the gif fading before it has been completely played. Perhaps I need to work out on the size of the animation so it can be download faster.

Comment: Okay. Is this what you wrote in your code? 

`$( window ).load(function() {
   $(".animation").delay(9500).fadeOut(400);
});`

Comment: Yes, and the js as an external file